# Update the display format value with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, date-time

I have SharePoint list hosted in SharePoint online.

I need to change the display format for the modified filed to standard from friendly using CSOM code. I am able to do it through UI.

Below is the code snippet I used to change:

```
                   Field f = splist.Fields.GetByTitle("Modified");
                    FieldDateTime field = ctx.CastTo <FieldDateTime> (f);
                    // FieldDateTime dateTime = 
                    field.DisplayFormat = DateTimeFieldFormatType.DateTime;
                    field.Update();
                    splist.Update();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `FriendlyDisplayFormat` of the field as below:

```
Field f = splist.Fields.GetByTitle("Modified");
FieldDateTime field = ctx.CastTo <FieldDateTime> (f);
// FieldDateTime dateTime = 
//field.DisplayFormat = DateTimeFieldFormatType.DateTime;
field.FriendlyDisplayFormat = DateTimeFieldFriendlyFormatType.Disabled;
field.Update();
splist.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Reference - [DateTimeFieldFriendlyFormatType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.datetimefieldfriendlyformattype.aspx)